# I get exit error 6 when building a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running `sudo docker compose -f docker-compose.development.yml up --build` to build my project container
but I'm getting this error:

```
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c curl -fLo install.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh     && chmod +x install.sh && sh install.sh && cp ./bin/air /bin/air]: exit code: 6
```

here's my docker file:

```
FROM golang:1.17.5-stretch

ARG GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_USER
ARG GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git

# private gitlab package credentials
RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com
RUN touch ~/.netrc
RUN chmod 600 ~/.netrc
RUN echo "machine gitlab.com login ${GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_USER} password ${GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD}" >> ~/.netrc


WORKDIR /app

# RUN go mod download
# # COPY the source code as the last step
# COPY . .

RUN curl -fLo install.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh \
    && chmod +x install.sh && sh install.sh && cp ./bin/air /bin/air

RUN curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.45.2


CMD air
```

and this is my docker-compose.development.yml file:

```
services:
  graphql:
    container_name: chimp-bff-development
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
      args:
        GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_USER: $GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_USER
        GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD: $GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "$PORT:$PORT"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    networks:
      - chimpbff-bridge
  redis:
    hostname: $RDB_HOST_NAME
    container_name: chimpbff_redis
    build:
      context: ./Docker/redis
      args:
        - APQ_RDB_USERNAME=$APQ_RDB_USERNAME
        - APQ_RBD_PASSWORD=$APQ_RBD_PASSWORD
        - RBD_PORT=$RBD_PORT
    expose:
      - $RBD_PORT
    volumes:
      - ./Docker/data/redis:/data
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=511
    # restart: always
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "5"
        max-size: "10m"
    networks:
      - chimpbff-bridge

networks:
  chimpbff-bridge:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: chimp-bridge
```

what does exit code 6 means? and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Try replacing your first `curl` command with this one from the docs `curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin`